# Vector Iterators Incompatible when in class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, iterator

I've got a pretty simple class with a vector as a private variable like so:

```
#include "Zombie.h"
#include <vector>

class CGame{
public:
CGame();
void DoVectorStuff();
private:
std::vector<Zombie> zombies;
};
```

In the function DoVectorStuff() im just looping through the vector like so:

```
for(std::vector<Zombie>::iterator it = zombies.begin(); it != zombies.end(); ++it)
{
   it->Update(delta);
}
```

Which is causing Visual Studio 2010 to give me a debug assertion when I run it. The same code worked fine when it was in a function by itself, I assume its something to do with me adding it to a class but I can't figure out what.

EDIT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K9GY.png This is the error I'm getting.

Comment: shouldn't the type of the iterator be std::vector<Zombie>::iterator ?

Comment: Show the definition of DoVectorStuff().

Comment: My fault, the code got screwed up when I put it in using <pre><code> tags. It's like that in the real code.

Comment: @Mahesh the defintion is literally just that.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you forgot the initial `CGame::` in your declaration of `DoVectorStuff()`.  If not, post the debug message.

Comment: @MattPhillips I've editted the question.

Comment: Thanks.  You should look at the file/line it gave you.  I expect it's a declaration of `vector` which conflicts with `std::vector`.  But you use `std::`... So is `#include <vector>` pulling up the non-`std` file?  Try `#include <sys/vector>` perhaps though that's just a guess.

Comment: Cannot be answered without a testcase. Your post does not reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MattPhillips: What on earth is `sys/vector`?

Comment: The error is likely in the code inside the loop, which you omitted. Probably you are using an invalidated iterator or something.

Comment: BTW this is a _runtime_ error, so there are no compilation problems. He's invalidating his iterator somewhere in code that we cannot see.

Comment: @Tomalak I seem to remember library files stored in a folder named 'sys' at some point--hey, I said it was a guess. :) As for it being a runtime error, *nice catch*.  The weird thing is that according to OP, this code worked outside of a class.  But clearly, we need to see what's in the loop.

Comment: I'll take a look when I'm home later and provide the rest of the code later.

Comment: @MattPhillips: Linux API files, sure :)

Answer (score 2):

The assertion you are getting **vector iterators imcompatible** indicates that you are trying to compare iterators from different vectors.

Typically you can get these by

**POSSIBILITY 1**

```
std::vector<int> foo( 100 );
std::vector<int> bar( 100 );

for( std::vector<int>::iterator iter = foo.begin();
    iter != bar.end();
    ++iter )
{
    std::cout << *iter;
}
```

Notice the above code and you will notice that I am comparing iter that is a iterator from `foo vector` to `bar.end()`

**POSSIBILITY 2**

Another way you can get the same error is by hanging on to invalid iterators.

```
std::vector<int> foo( 3 );
std::vector<int>::iterator enditer = foo.end();

foo.push_back( 3 );
foo.push_back( 3 );
foo.push_back( 3 );  // can invalidate endIter above


for( std::vector<int>::iterator iter = foo.begin();
    iter != enditer;
    ++iter )
{
    std::cout << *iter;
}
```

Notice how in the above code I have hanged on to **endIter** which can be invalidated by adding more elements to **foo**

Answer (score 1):

Wild Guess: `Zombie::Update` updates, among other things, the `zombies` vector, invalidating the iterator `it`. Do zombies die or reproduce during their `Update` cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
std::vector<Zombie>::iterator
```

instead of

```
std::vector::iterator
```

Comment: My fault, the code got screwed up when I put it in using <pre><code> tags. It's like that in the real code.

Comment: Then what assertion error are you getting when you run the program?